# How can I fix Appendchild is not a function and variable is not defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a feature in my card game where pressing a button will create a new HTML element that contains the card. (In my HTML I am using a onclick event). With the following code I get both an error that says appendchild is not a function as well as cardResult is undefined. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
function pickNewCard() {
let newCard = document.createElement('p');
newCard.innerHTML = cardResult.name;
document.getElementsByClassName('card').appendChild(newCard); }
```

The pick a card function does work in my previous function that only changes the same HTML element when the button is pressed:

```
function pickCard() {
let cardResult = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)];   
document.getElementById('card').innerHTML = cardResult.name;    
currentCard = cardResult; }
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements. You have to iterate through the list and find the element to which you want to append the new card.

Comment: Where did you define `cardResult` in `pickNewCard`?